# Multiple searches within a search result set (stored procedure)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Multiple searches within a search result set while using all the search terms used in in that session.

For example, I have a table `User` (`UserId, UserName, UserAddress, UserCity`)

What I am trying to do is, I want to search all the columns in the table, for example using a user's name, (which might give me a result set consisting of more than 1 result). I want to be able to search within the result set again using a new search term (not necessarily have to have the first search term in the search field), but this time, it must search within the result set of the 1st search. This might go on breaking down the result set until what is required is found.

Sorry if I might sound very confusing with my request. I've tried and still got no clue to where to start with. I've tried googling and browsed through this website, but couldn't find what i am really trying to find.

Comment: Are you looking for [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)?

Comment: not necessarily. the search query could be a single term as well. but it is required to search within the search result-set until you get the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to search within the result-set again using a new
>   search term [...], but this time, it must search within the result set
>   of the 1st search .This might go on breaking down the result-set until
>   what is required is found.

It seems to me that you have not yet understood that SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. And yes, there are stored procedures, but these are a procedural extension to SQL and don't alter the fact that SQL is essentially declarative.

So instead of *"breaking down the result-set until what is required is found"*, you specify all criteria at once, and preferably do so without resorting to a stored procedure until you've understood non-procedural SQL.

To give you an example, a query using multiple *predicates* (facts about the desired result specified in a `WHERE` clause) might look like this:

```
SELECT UserId FROM User
 WHERE UserName LIKE 'cook%'
   AND UserAddress LIKE 'sesam%'
   AND UserCity = 'Hamburg';
```